QGIS - filter (exclude) Atlaspages with empty legend
Is there a way to filter/exclude all pages of a Atlas-setting that have no selected legend information?

Depends on how your legend is created. If this is a followup to the roads/paths atlas question please see my updated answer there: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/479423/15183 .

The generic answer is yes.
Create a virtual field on the atlas coverage layer that evaluates to 0 if the "selected legend information" is empty, then filter the atlas coverage layer on the virtual field and include only coverage features that have a value != 0 in the filter field.
